# Camlquery: Getting items from top root folder of list

Tags: list, caml-query, folder

I know how to get items from a folder inside a list (example below)

```
CamlQuery caml = new CamlQuery();
caml.FolderServerRelativeUrl = "/folder/path";
```

But how do you get the items from just the top root folder? I don't want to get all items, but just from that top path before it goes into any folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case you don't need to specify `CamlQuery.FolderServerRelativeUrl property`  at all.
The following example demonstrates how to retrieve items of top folder in List:

```
var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
var items = list.GetItems(new CamlQuery());
ctx.Load(items);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

If you are interested in returning only items *associated with files* then you could consider the following example:

```
var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
var items = list.GetItems(CreateItemsQuery());
ctx.Load(items);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

where

```
public static CamlQuery CreateItemsQuery()
{
    return new CamlQuery()
    {
        ViewXml = "<View ><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"FSObjType\" /><Value Type=\"Integer\">0</Value></Eq></Where></Query>\r\n</View>"
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need this:

```
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
SPListItemCollection myItems = list.GetItems(query);
```

By default you get the files under the root folder.
[Scopes in a CAML Query](http://www.codegrimoire.com/2013/08/scopes-in-caml-query.html)